# Creating a generic xml linq search based on attribute name/value pairs

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a set of functions I'm working on, and one of them is to parse an XML file, and return the elements that match to the attribute-based conditions that I have.

This is a sample of the XML I have to use:

```
 <rs:insert>
<z:row Inst='AM5001' Event='EventA' HostName='HostA' EventType='NORMAL' TXID='0000003327'/>
<z:row Inst='AM5001' Event='EventB' HostName='HostB' EventType='NORMAL' TXID='0000011173'/>
<z:row Inst='AM4067' Event='EventA' HostName='HostA' EventType='NORMAL' TXID='0000011175'/>
<z:row Inst='AM5546' Event='EventC' HostName='HostC' EventType='NORMAL' TXID='0000011177'/>
<z:row Inst='AM4567' Event='EventQ' HostName='HostD' EventType='NORMAL' TXID='0000011593'/>
```

and this is a snippet of what I've got so far:

```
internal protected IEnumerable<XElement> GetElement(XDocument oXMLDoc
        , List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SearchCriteria)
    {
        var vElementQuery = oXMLDoc.Elements()
            .Where(e => SearchCriteria.ForEach(sc => e.Attribute(sc.Key).Value.ToUpper() == sc.Value.ToUpper()))
            .Select(e => e);

        foreach (var xElement in vElementQuery)
        {
            yield return xElement;
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error in my where clause of the vElementQuery :

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

In simplicity, I would be querying based on Inst and Event, but occasionally I would need to based on hostname and Eventtype also.

Basically, I don't know how many attribute conditions I will need to match on, so I could like to add them in as a list or an array, thinking a `KeyValuePair` would be useful as it gives me the name and the comparison (value) that I need.

Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Where` requires a predicate: A function that takes an `e` (`XElement` in this case) and returns a `bool`.

Instead, you're trying to return the result of `SearchCriteria.ForEach()`, which returns `void`. All it does is iterate over the collection and call a `void` lambda for each item. So you can't use it as the body of a predicate. That would be your next problem after you fix this one, but the same fix takes care of both.

```
.Where(e => 
    SearchCriteria.ForEach(sc => 
        e.Attribute(sc.Key).Value.ToUpper() == sc.Value.ToUpper()
    )
)
```

Because `ForEach` returns `void`, it takes a lambda that returns `void`. The body of a function must be a statement. In a lambda, if the return type isn't `void`, and the body is an expression, the result of that expression is returned -- call it an implicit return statement. But here the return value is void -- that's established by [the parameter type of `ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void ForEach(
    Action<T> action
)
```

`Action<T>` has one parameter and no return type. And whatever inference rules the compiler uses result in it assuming that you're trying to write a void lambda, rather than that you're trying to give `ForEach` a predicate.

Here's the body of the lambda you're giving it:

```
e.Attribute(sc.Key).Value.ToUpper() == sc.Value.ToUpper()
```

Without the compiler supplying an implicit `return` in front of it, that's not a statement. It's an expression. As a statement, it's not legal C#. Try compiling this:

```
1 != 2;
```

Same error. C or Perl wouldn't care but C# does.

I think you might want `Any` instead of `ForEach`:

```
.Where(e => 
    SearchCriteria.Any(sc => 
        e.Attribute(sc.Key).Value.ToUpper() == sc.Value.ToUpper()
    )
)
```

That is to say, return any `e` where any of the search criteria matches any of its attributes. `Any` takes a predicate and returns `bool`, fixing both errors.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the breakdown - that'll help me in the future.